# Rude expression for interfering with a discussion

Tags: offensive-language

What rude expression would fit most the next situation:

Let's say some people are in a meeting talking about serious work-related stuff. At a point, one of the persons makes a remark to another about not being shaved. Then, the offended person defends itself by saying that the remark is off-topic and should not be discussed in public work-related meeting. Then, a 3rd person would like to intervene by saying something equivalent to 'let me intervene' but in a very rude manner. What exactly would the 3rd person say ? Closest thing I could come up is 'let me stick in' . Is there something worse that can be used in this case ?

Comment: A person defends itself? Forget sticking anything into anything. That often means something rude or dumb.  "I'm going to cut you off right there".

Comment: at a public meaning you might use the more formal "let me interject", which is not rude at , unless the person is interjecting improperly and then it is the interjection, not the wording that is rude.

Comment: "shut up and let me talk" seems to be a common rude way of butting in even if justified.  I'm not sure I can write that up as a comprehensive enough reply to make it an answer.  Even if the interruption is justified...telling someone to "shut up" is rude where a forceful "I need to interject here" is less rude even if forceful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly rude term for interrupting is to "butt in".

> to interrupt a conversation or discussion or someone who is talking

[Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/butt-in)

Answer (score 3):

stick your oar in

so the 3rd person would say they were "going to stick their oar in"

> to say or do something that annoys other people because they have not
>   asked you to join their conversation or activity:

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-stick-your-oar-in

Comment: That is not rude.

Comment: rude as in offensive? no but rude as in impolite I would say it was. Being accused of sticking your oar in is not a compliment

Comment: No, it is not impolite if you say; I'm going to stick my oar in here. It just means; I'm going to jump into the discussion and give me opinion. It is  not rude if said like that at all. It's just colorful.

Comment: "Stick your nose in" would seem more applicable.

Comment: Yes, it fits the scenario but it's not rude (enough). Good alternative though.